# Angular 4 and Umbraco Working Together

Tags: umbraco

I've heard that Umbraco is written in Angular 1.  Is it possible to run a web site written in Angular 4 on Umbraco?

Do they play well together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backend of Umbraco is implemented using AngularJS (v1). The frontend of Umbraco uses Razor to output serverside data or you can implement your own WebAPI controllers on top of Umbraco to output data to a webapplication implemented by the framework of your preference.

So yes, if you want to use it for the website itself, it fits perfectly fine. You'll have to implement your own [Web API Controllers](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/)

If you want to use Angular to extend the Umbraco backoffice, you'll want to use AngularJS (v1)

Comment: There's a 2014 24 Days in Umbraco article which goes over how you might do this with Angular 1.3: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/angular-powered-frontend ; there's even a github project: https://github.com/skybrud/AngularPoweredUmbracoFrontend and a live demo: http://24days.skybrud.dk/subpage-2 . All links still working 02/02/18.